# Possible to render WPF Form in SlimDX ? [C# .NET]

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, overlay

So, programs like Curse and Overwolf can overlay most games. I guess that works with DLL Injection and DirectX hooking. So if you would want to render fancy GUI's in the game as an Overlay you would have to create a whole control system from scratch, but that's too much work. So i figured since WPF is DX based, is it possible to draw and interact with a WPF Form in the Overlay, which uses SlimDX to render stuff ?